# Dúvida com inner join sql em várias tabelas

Tags: mysql

Eu tenho três tabelas. `Usuários`, `Anúncios` e `Fotos`.

A *query* que eu estou fazendo é para pegar o `id` do Anúncio, o `Título`, a `Quantidade` de visualizações e a primeira foto deste anúncio da tabela de fotos. Já que um único anúncio pode ter várias fotos. Até aí tudo bem, mas quando eu coloco o *group by* me dá este erro:

> 1055 - Expression #5 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'vivachapeco.fotosanuncio.foto' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Eu preciso pegar uma única foto porque na página onde será exibido esta *query*, o resultado se repete só por causa da quantidade de fotos. Então, o anúncio com `id` 1 vai ser repetido 5 vezes porque ele possui 5 fotos, quando na verdade, gostaria de ter apenas uma foto dele.

A *query* está assim:

```
SELECT `anuncios`.`id_anuncio`, `anuncios`.`id_user`, `anuncios`.`titulo`,
       `anuncios`.`visualizacoes`, `fotosanuncio`.`foto`
FROM `anuncios`
INNER JOIN `users` 
    ON `users`.`id_user` = `anuncios`.`id_user`
INNER JOIN `fotosanuncio` 
    ON `fotosanuncio`.`id_anuncio` = `anuncios`.`id_anuncio`
    WHERE `users`.`id_user` = 3
GROUP BY `fotosanuncio`.`id_anuncio`;
```

Já se eu tiro a *group by*, funciona "corretamente", porém, como tenho o anúncio, 1 e 2 com uma foto cada uma e o anúncio 3 com duas fotos, me retorna 4 valores, ao invés de retornar 3 valores já que a intensão é agrupar todos os resultados das fotos por anúncio.

Comment: Por regra, tudo que tiver dentro de select tem que estar no group by

Comment: Everson, e como ficaria o group by então? Eu acrescentei o `fotosanuncios`.`id_anuncio` no select e mesmo assim continua dando o messmo erro.

Comment: `group by anuncios.id_anuncio, anuncios.id_user, anuncios.titulo, anuncios.visualizacoes, fotosanuncio.foto`, vai parar de gerar o erro, mas talvez não traga os registros que você necessita.

Comment: Testei aqui e retorna como se não tivesse o group by. Retorna todos os dados, então, repetindo o anúncio que tem mais de uma foto.

Comment: Como é a tabela fotosanuncio, ela possui algum id? posta a estrutura dela

Answer (score 0):

@Felipe Paz... isso acontece porque o relacionamento de fotos com anuncio é de muitos para um (n:1). Nesse caso, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT `anuncios`.`id_anuncio`, `anuncios`.`id_user`, 
`anuncios`.`titulo`, `anuncios`.`visualizacoes`, MAX(`fotosanuncio`.`foto`)
FROM `anuncios`
INNER JOIN `users` 
ON `users`.`id_user` = `anuncios`.`id_user`
INNER JOIN `fotosanuncio` 
ON `fotosanuncio`.`id_anuncio` = `anuncios`.`id_anuncio`
WHERE `users`.`id_user` = 3
GROUP BY `anuncios`.`id_anuncio`, `anuncios`.`id_user`, 
`anuncios`.`titulo`,`anuncios`.`visualizacoes`;
```

Outra maneira seria utilizar a instrução **DISTINCT**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `anuncios`.`id_anuncio`, `anuncios`.`id_user`, 
`anuncios`.`titulo`, `anuncios`.`visualizacoes`, `fotosanuncio`.`foto`
FROM `anuncios`
INNER JOIN `users` 
ON `users`.`id_user` = `anuncios`.`id_user`
INNER JOIN `fotosanuncio` 
ON `fotosanuncio`.`id_anuncio` = `anuncios`.`id_anuncio`
WHERE `users`.`id_user` = 3;
```

Comment: Bom, o que eu fiz para resolver  tudo isso foi uma leve gambiarra. Apenas acrescentei uma coluna na tabela de anúncios como fotocapa. Então, mesmo que haja muitas fotos para o anúncio, esta coluna vai ser preenchida apenas com a primeira foto. E assim resolvi o que eu precisava, contudo, vou testar mais a sugestão dada pelo Cleo e posto os resultados.

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser visualizar a primeira foto salva você pode utilizar o [MIN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) caso queria ultima inserida você pode utilizar o [MAX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max), note que te perguntei se havia uma coluna para identificarmos as fotos na sua tabela `fotosanuncio` pois não podemos utilizar `min()` ou `max()` na coluna com o nome ou caminho da foto, por ser um campo texto pode não trazer o resultado esperado em todos os casos.

No exemplo abaixo eu relacionei a tabela a uma seleção agrupando pelo anúncio, supondo que sua tabela de foto possua uma cooluna de `id_fotos`.

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo funcionando online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/442278/10)

```
SELECT anuncios.id_anuncio
   , anuncios.id_user
   , anuncios.titulo
   , anuncios.visualizacoes
   , foto
FROM anuncios
INNER JOIN users 
    ON users.id_user = anuncios.id_user
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    MIN(id_fotos)
    , foto
    , id_anuncio
  FROM fotosanuncio
  GROUP BY id_anuncio
) fotosanuncio2 
  ON fotosanuncio2.id_anuncio = anuncios.id_anuncio
group by anuncios.id_anuncio
, anuncios.id_user
, anuncios.titulo
, anuncios.visualizacoes
, fotosanuncio2.id_anuncio
```

Answer (score 0):

se você executar esse comando: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%sql_mode%'` vai perceber que o valor possui essa string `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

o que você pode fazer é copiar o valor, ir no arquivo my.ini aidicionar a variavel sql_mode com o valor que retornou da consulta acima retirando apenas o `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` o que te deixa livre para fazer agrupamentos não agregados.